# Auto trigger server deploy and build on git push

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, continuous-integration, vps

I'am looking for a simple and straightforward way to deploy a node application from the repo service (bitbucket or gitlab) to a separate server/vps.

I want to proceed so that a push to the repo would trigger a deploy on the server (one for a staging environment and one for production) When initially looking into this I get uncertain on what would be best, easiest, most efficient, best practice and so on. What tools should I pick, a gitlab runner or  is it possible with pm2, some webhook or some other node npm service that could be installed on the vps for this? Any suggestions or links to further info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you trying CI/CD tool like Jenkins, but I needs to be run separately.

You can set cron at Jenkins to check repo changes, it's the easiest way. Better way would be using webhooks like [Bitbucket Webhook Jenkins](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.nerdwin15.stash-stash-webhook-jenkins/server/overview) addon. [Here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html) is setup guide for Gitlab.

[Jenkins installation guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins)

Comment: thanks for a quick response on this. I'm familiar with Jenkis but have never used it. seems ok, but also a bit to complicated if I have to have Jenkins installed on a separate server apart from the git-repo and the vps where the app resides. There should be simpler solutions? The only thing that the VPS need to do is some CLI commands to retrieve updates from the git repo, then npm install and move files and folders.

Comment: You need to run some service which will listen on changes. You could run Jenkins in docker, so it wont be much configuration

Comment: using jenkins on the same server as the vps/application would (not) be possible or a bad idea? 

with '... I needs to be run separately' ...you mean a separate service on the vps (using another port), not necessarily a separate server?

Comment: It can be seprate service